# Is it a valid noun "the built"?

Tags: nouns, past-tense, books

I am reading a book **The Business of the 21st Century** and came across the word *"built"* used as a noun.

> Building genuine wealth is as much about
>   the *builder* as it is about the *built*.

It is written exactly in that format -- "builder" and "built" are italic.

I cannot find a noun form of the word "built". Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Yes, it's okay but you are only **apt** to find it in academic-type texts. See the book: *The Raw and the Cooked* by Claude Lévi-Strauss. It is indirectly traceable to usages in literary criticism influenced by the French.

Comment: Using a past participle (probably via the adjective) is not ultra-common, but by no means unknown. 'Into the unknown.' 'The dammed.' 'The injured and dead.' 'The disabled and unemployed.' Note that there is no verb 'unemploy'. 'The accused.' //// The sense here is 'that which is / has been built'; the sense of 'built' meaning 'form of a structure (eg the built/build of a ship)' is obsolete.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The damned. Yes, but the ones you cite are usual. They are in the dictionary. "The built" is not. –

Comment: @Lambie 'Not in the dictionary' (I've re-ordered). Have you checked? Or have you checked in **a"" dictionary? Or two ...? // But yes, this particular usage is _very_ rare.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My point is **completely different than yours**. There is a "thing" where PPs are used where they are often not in dictionaries: The Raw and The Cooked. And it is ***usually*** in academic texts, often patterned on French structuralism *et al*.

Comment: It is like, the ruler, and the ruled; the killer and the killed; the tormentor and the tormented.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, **built** is a nominalised adjective: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective

> The most common appearance of the nominalized adjective in English is when an adjective is used to indicate a collective group. This happens in the case where a phrase such as the poor people becomes the poor. The adjective poor is nominalized, and the noun people disappears. ...

Thus we have

"The odd" = The numbers that are not even (or the people or things that are abnormal, etc.)

"The lame" = the lame people or lame animals.

"The built" = the built structures.

> Another case is when an adjective is used to denote a single object with the property, as in "you take the long route, and I'll take the short". Here the short stands for "the short route".

Comment: The thing is that popular nominalized adjectives like the poor become so popular that they are put in the dictionaries. E.g. if I paste "poor" in Google Translate, it shows me  translations categorized by parts of speech: Noun: ..., Verb: ... and so on. But, unfortunately, the word "built" has a single category Adjective. Neither other online dictionaries have a noun definition.

Comment: Thanks for the wiki page, it is really useful.